# Encog Lunar Lander Extended

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, encog, simulated-annealing

This question is with reference to [C#'s Lunar Lander Example](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/tree/master/ConsoleExamples/Examples/Lunar) obtained in Encog repository. As the example suggests, I am using NeuralSimulatedAnnealing to train my multi-layer feedforward network (50 epoch's)

```
BasicNetwork network = CreateNetwork();

IMLTrain train;
train = new NeuralSimulatedAnnealing(network, new PilotScore(), 10, 2, 100);
```

_

```
public static BasicNetwork CreateNetwork() {
    var pattern = new FeedForwardPattern {InputNeurons = 3};
    pattern.AddHiddenLayer(50);
    pattern.OutputNeurons = 1;
    pattern.ActivationFunction = new ActivationTANH();
    var network = (BasicNetwork) pattern.Generate();
    network.Reset();
    return network;
}
```

The example works great and neural pilot exactly learns how to land the spaceship in given conditions, however I want something more out of it!

To do that I created a class globals such as below and also modified a line in LanderSimulator class

```
namespace Encog.Examples.Lunar
{
    class globals
    {
        public static int fuelConsumption { get; set; }
    }
}
```

_

```
 public void Turn(bool thrust){
    Seconds++;
    Velocity -= Gravity;
    Altitude += Velocity;

    if (thrust && Fuel > 0)
    {
        Fuel-= globals.fuelConsumption;    //changed instead of Fuel--;
        Velocity += Thrust;
    }

    Velocity = Math.Max(-TerminalVelocity, Velocity);
    Velocity = Math.Min(TerminalVelocity, Velocity);

    if (Altitude < 0)
        Altitude = 0;
}
```

So now depending upon the **fuelConsumption** variable the fuel is consumed on each thrust. Then I tried with three different values of fuelConsumption and following were the respective best scores for individual networks:

```
//NETWORK 1
globals.fuelConsumption = 1;
bestScore: 7986

//NETWORK 2
globals.fuelConsumption = 5;
bestScore: 7422

//NETWORK 3
globals.fuelConsumption = 10;
bestScore: 6921
```

When I tested these networks on each other the results were disappointing:

- network 1 showed score of -39591 and -39661 when fuelConsumed was 5
  and 10 respectively.
- network 2 showed score of -8832 and -35671 when fuelConsumed was
  1 and 10 respectively.
- network 3 showed score of -24510 and -19697 when fuelConsumed was 1 and 5 respectively.

So I tried to train one single network for all three scenarios like below:

```
int epoch;

epoch = 1;
globals.fuelConsumption = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    train.Iteration();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Score:" + train.Error);
    epoch++;
}
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");

epoch = 1;
globals.fuelConsumption = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    train.Iteration();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Score:" + train.Error);
    epoch++;
}
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");
epoch = 1;
globals.fuelConsumption = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    train.Iteration();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Score:" + train.Error);
    epoch++;
}

Console.WriteLine(@"The score of experienced pilot is:");
network = (BasicNetwork) train.Method;

var pilot = new NeuralPilot(network, false);
globals.fuelConsumption = 1;
Console.WriteLine("@1: " + pilot.ScorePilot());
globals.fuelConsumption = 5;
Console.WriteLine("@5: " + pilot.ScorePilot());
globals.fuelConsumption = 10;
Console.WriteLine("@10: " + pilot.ScorePilot());
```

But results are again the same

```
The score of experienced pilot is:
@1: -27485
@5: -27565
@10: 7448
```

**How do I create a neural pilot that would deliver me the best score in all three scenarios?**

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this puzzle I switched to **NEAT networks** rather than using traditional feed forward or recurrent networks. Here were some interesting changes in the code..

```
NEATPopulation network = CreateNetwork();
TrainEA train = default(TrainEA);
```

_

```
public static NEATPopulation CreateNetwork(){
    int inputNeurons = 3;
    int outputNeurons = 1;
    NEATPopulation network = new NEATPopulation(inputNeurons, outputNeurons, 100);
    network.Reset();
    return network;
}
```

And then after tweaking some parameters in **NeuralPilot class**,

```
private readonly NEATNetwork _network;

public NeuralPilot(NEATNetwork network, bool track)
```

I had to make change in **ScorePilot function** since NEATNetoworks use SteepenedSigmoidActivation by default rather than traditional ActivationLinear or ActivatonTanH on outputs

```
bool thrust;

if (value > 0.5){       //changed from, if (value > 0){
    thrust = true;
    if (_track)
        Console.WriteLine(@"THRUST");
}
else
    thrust = false;
```

So now training one single network looks like below:

```
OriginalNEATSpeciation speciation = default(OriginalNEATSpeciation);
speciation = new OriginalNEATSpeciation();

int epoch;
double best_1, best_5, best_10;
best_1 = best_5 = best_10 = 0;

train = NEATUtil.ConstructNEATTrainer(network, new PilotScore());
train.Speciation = speciation;

epoch = 1;
globals.fuelConsumption = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    train.Iteration();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Score:" + train.Error);
    best_1 = train.Error;
    epoch++;
}
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");

train = NEATUtil.ConstructNEATTrainer(network, new PilotScore());
train.Speciation = speciation;

epoch = 1;
globals.fuelConsumption = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    train.Iteration();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Score:" + train.Error);
    best_5 = train.Error;
    epoch++;
}
Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------");

train = NEATUtil.ConstructNEATTrainer(network, new PilotScore());
train.Speciation = speciation;

epoch = 1;
globals.fuelConsumption = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    train.Iteration();
    Console.WriteLine(@"Epoch #" + epoch + @" Score:" + train.Error);
    best_10 = train.Error;
    epoch++;
}

Console.WriteLine(@"The score of experienced pilot is:");

NEATNetwork trainedNetwork = default(NEATNetwork);
trainedNetwork = (NEATNetwork)train.CODEC.Decode(network.BestGenome);

var pilot = new NeuralPilot(trainedNetwork, false);
globals.fuelConsumption = 1;
Console.WriteLine("@bestScore of " + best_1.ToString() +" @1: liveScore is " + pilot.ScorePilot());
globals.fuelConsumption = 5;
Console.WriteLine("@bestScore of " + best_5.ToString() + " @5: liveScore is " + pilot.ScorePilot());
globals.fuelConsumption = 10;
Console.WriteLine("@bestScore of " + best_10.ToString() + " @10: liveScore is " + pilot.ScorePilot());
```

*The results go dicey! Following are some results on random tests:*

```
The score of experienced pilot is:
@bestScore of 5540 @1: liveScore is -4954
@bestScore of 1160 @5: liveScore is 3823
@bestScore of 3196 @10: liveScore is 3196

The score of experienced pilot is:
@bestScore of 7455 @1: liveScore is 8227
@bestScore of 6324 @5: liveScore is 7427
@bestScore of 6427 @10: liveScore is 6427

The score of experienced pilot is:
@bestScore of 5322 @1: liveScore is -4617
@bestScore of 1898 @5: liveScore is 9531
@bestScore of 2086 @10: liveScore is 2086

The score of experienced pilot is:
@bestScore of 7493 @1: liveScore is -3848
@bestScore of 4907 @5: liveScore is -13840
@bestScore of 4954 @10: liveScore is 4954

The score of experienced pilot is:
@bestScore of 6560 @1: liveScore is 4046
@bestScore of 5775 @5: liveScore is 3366
@bestScore of 2516 @10: liveScore is 2516
```

As you can see *we did managed to get positive score all the way in second scenario* but, there doesn't seem to be any relation between the final network performance and the initial best score values. **Hence, the issue might be resolved but not in satisfactory manner.**

Comment: note that same **network** and **speciation** are used successively but over new **trainer** each time. Is it logically correct?